# If Statement Laravel with substr

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to achieve by sorting it if it is a globe or smart number, but it doesn't work. Thank you in Advance. Anyways this is my code. If you have any question please ask me or I will explain more.

```
@if (substr($contact->mobile, 0, 5) == "63929" || "63959")
 <span class="btn btn-success">Smart</span>
@elseif(substr($contact->mobile, 0, 5) == "63905" || "63906" || "63997")
  <span class="btn btn-primary">Globe</span>
@endif
```

Comment: Little remark.
Don't place code like that in your templates. 
E.g. you can add method into your `Contact` model like this: https://pastebin.com/MH9cgw7Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You doing your if statements wrong, you have to repeat the whole condition for every Or test:

```
@if (substr($contact->mobile, 0, 5) == "63929" || substr($contact->mobile, 0, 5) == "63959")
    <span class="btn btn-success">Smart</span>
@elseif(substr($contact->mobile, 0, 5) == "63905" || substr($contact->mobile, 0, 5) == "63906" || substr($contact->mobile, 0, 5) == "63997")
    <span class="btn btn-primary">Globe</span>
@endif
```

A cleaner solution for your blade template would define a new function on your Contact model like this, for example:

```
// Model Contact
public function startsWith($numbers) {
    return in_array(substr($this->mobile, 0, 5), $numbers);
}

// blade template
@if ($contact->startsWith(["63929", "63959"]))
```

Comment: I will mark as the best answer just need to wait for 9 minutes

Comment: Any idea how to make how many globe or smart? as in count ? Thank you again

Comment: any idea how to count all the globe and smart separately

Comment: has error syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '('

Comment: Sorry, there was a bracket missing in the blade template code.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition doesn't work.

PHP sees two conditions here because of the `||`. The last part is always true

```
substr($contact->mobile, 0, 5) == "63929" || "63959"
```

You should use `in_array`.

```
@if (in_array(substr($contact->mobile, 0, 5), ["63929", "63959"])
  <span>
@endif
```